# asynch.errors.UnexpectedPacketFromServerError: Code: 102. Unexpected packet from server <host:port> (expected Hello or Exception, got Unknown packet)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, clickhouse

I'm trying to connect to clickhouse with sqlalchemy. I'm using:

- python3.11
- clickhouse-driver == 0.2.6
- sqlalchemy == 2.0.23
- clickhouse-sqlalchemy == 0.3.0
- asynch == 0.2.3
- asyncio == 3.4.3

Here is my script I used:

```py
import asyncio
import contextlib
import pydantic
import traceback
import typing
from sqlalchemy import text, TextClause, engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine, AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool, QueuePool 

class AsyncDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ch_uri: str = "clickhouse+asynch://admin:Password123@host:31123/db"
        self.ch_engine: AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(
            url=self.ch_uri,
            echo=False,
            pool_size=100,
            max_overflow=20,
            poolclass=QueuePool,
        )
        self.ch_session: AsyncSession = AsyncSession(bind=self.ch_engine)
        self.ch_pool: Pool = self.ch_engine.pool

async_db: AsyncDatabase = AsyncDatabase()

@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def get_ch_session() -> typing.AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    try:
        yield async_db.ch_session
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.print_exc())
        await async_db.ch_session.rollback()
    finally:
        await async_db.ch_session.close()


async def hello() -> str:
    session: AsyncSession = None
    async with get_ch_session() as session:
        stmt: TextClause = text("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1")
        result: engine.Result = await session.execute(stmt)
        print(result.all())

    return "ok"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(hello())
```

I did try without async but still got the same error
`asynch.errors.UnexpectedPacketFromServerError: Code: 102. Unexpected packet from server host:31123 (expected Hello or Exception, got Unknown packet)`

when I use DataGrid to connect with above creds, it works fine. so I think it's not about the `31123` port

I stuck on this for 5 hrs, all answers from the web doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 2):

You tried to use TCP Native protocol, but connected to HTTP based port

look `grep tcp_port /var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/config.xml`
and use this value